# Listening events in a web service or API over Database changes

Tags: c#, sql, web, listeners

I have this scenario, and I don't really know where to start. Suppose there's a Web service-like app (might be API tho) hosted on a server. That app receives a request to proccess some data (through some method we will call processData(data theData)).

On the other side, there's a robot (might be installed on the same server) that procceses the data. So, The web-service inserts the request on a common Database (both programms have access to it), and it's supposed to wait for that row to change and send the results back.

The robot periodically check the database for new rows, proccesses the data and set some sort of flag to that row, indicating that the data was processed.

So the main problem here is, what should the method proccessData(..) do to check for the changes of the data row?.

I know one way to do it: I can build an iteration block that checks for the row every x secs. But i don't want to do that. What I want to do is to build some sort of event listener, that triggers when the row changes. I know it might involve some asynchronous programming

I might be dreaming, but is that even possible in a web enviroment.?

I've been reading about a SqlDependency class, Async and AWait classes, etc..

Comment: It's very possible.  Can you give us a few more details?  What is your client?  How will you notify your users of the change?

Comment: My Client is an API that receives credit cards to be charged from multiple POS. Through the payment gateway there are multiple security components, and a centralized hob that receives every request from all those API's. Is there where the robot resides, is there where the Database resides also.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much control you have over design of this distributed system, it might be better for its architecture if you take a step back and try to think outside the domain of solutions you have narrowed the problem down to so far. You have identified the "main problem" to be finding a way for the distributed services to communicate with each other through the common database. Maybe that is a thought you should challenge.

There are many potential ways for these components to communicate and if your design goal is to reduce latency and thus avoid polling, it might in fact be the right way for the service that needs to be informed of completion of this work item to be informed of it right away. However, if in the future the throughput of this system has to increase, processing work items in bulk and instead poll for the information might become the only feasible option. This is also why I have chosen to word my answer a bit more generically and discuss the design of this distributed system more abstractly.

If after this consideration your answer remains the same and you do want immediate notification, consider having the component that processes a work item to notify the component(s) that need to be notified. As a general design principle for distributed systems, it is best to have the component that is most authoritative for a given set of data to also be the component to answer requests about that data. In this case, the data you have is the completion status of your work items, so the best component to act on this would be the component completing the work items. It might be better for that component to inform calling clients and components of that completion. Here it's also important to know if you only write this data to the database for the sake of communication between components or if those rows have any value beyond the completion of a given work item, such as for reporting purposes or performance indicators (KPIs).

I think there can be valid reasons, though, why you would not want to have such a call, such as reducing coupling between components or lack of access to communicate with the other component in a direct manner. There are many communication primitives that allow such notification, such as MSMQ under Windows, or Queues in Windows Azure. There are also reasons against it, such as dependency on a third component for communication within your system, which could reduce the availability of your system and lead to outages. The questions you might want to ask yourself here are: "How much work can my component do when everything around it goes down?" and "What are my design priorities for this system in terms of reliability and availability?"

So I think the main problem you might want to really try to solve fist is a bit more abstract: how should the interface through which components of this distributed system communicate look like?

If after all of this you remain set on having the interface of communication between those components be the SQL database, you could explore using INSERT and UPDATE triggers in SQL. You can easily look up the syntax of those commands and specify Stored Procedures that then get executed. In those stored procedures you would want to check the completion flag of any new rows and possibly restrain the number of rows you check by date or have an ID for the last processed work item. To then notify the other component, you could go as far as using the built-in stored procedure `XP_cmdshell` to execute command lines under Windows. The command you execute could be a simple tool that pings your service for completion of the task.

I'm sorry to have initially overlooked your suggestion to use SQL Query Notifications. That is also a feasible way and works through the Service Broker component. You would define a `SqlCommand`, as if normally querying your database, pass this to an instance of `SqlDependency` and then subscribe to the event called `OnChange`. Once you execute the `SqlCommand`, you should get calls to the event handler you added to `OnChange`.

I am not sure, however, how to get the exact changes to the database out of the `SqlNotificationEventArgs` object that will be passed to your event handler, so your query might need to be specific enough for the application to tell that the work item has completed whenever the query changes, or you might have to do another round-trip to the database from your application every time you are notified to be able to tell what exactly has changed.

Comment: Well, my initial approach was to set some sort of 'flag' on the database record, that indicates that the data has been proccesed. Then my SqlDependency checks for that flag to change. The problem seems to be the web-service. At the moment it creates the SqlDependency object, it continues he excecution and might end it without the data being proccesed, so I need to put that excetucion in some sort of idle process until something changes. What I did was declare a global flag on the web-service instance, the on-change event changes that flag, and the web-service iterates until that flag changes.

Comment: I surely do not like this approach, it envolves the same iteration I was trying to avoid, only that it will not be aginst the database record, but a global bit flag, witch I think will reduce dramatically the impact over the database.. (I don't know if i'm explaining myself rightly, I got so much ideas in my head right now, plus english is not my native language, so I'm sorry if you read this and makes no sense at all)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a *Message Queue*? The .Net framework already provides this facility. I would say let the web service manage an application level queue. The robot will request the same web service for things to do. Assuming that the data needed for the jobs are small, you can keep the whole thing in memory. I would rather not involve a database, if you don't already have one.